# Ola and Uber charging too much?

Tags: contract-law, india, professional-ethics

Uber and Ola takes a 20% cut from the total fare.

Is this legally too much?

What percent cut is good to take from the driver for connecting them with people legally and ethically?

Refer: [Indian limits the money Uber and Ola can charge](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ndtv.com/business/government-to-allow-uber-ola-to-charge-20-commission-on-ride-fares-2331223/amp/1)

Comment: @GregoryCurrie no no India has limited the money that they can charge even though it is not there in contract. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.ndtv.com/business/government-to-allow-uber-ola-to-charge-20-commission-on-ride-fares-2331223/amp/1

Comment: Perfect! Looks like you can now write your own answer for your question.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie this is not certain, it seems they are charging around 35%. That is why I wanted an answer from an authentic source.

Comment: There is no national law, so you have to look at the state level. The federal "guidelines" are a suggestion and not enforceable.  You have to approach this on a state-by-state basis.

Comment: @user6726 what do you think is ethically reasonable percent?

Comment: Whatever the parties agree to.